# How to resolve yarn error: Invalid violation: Expected a key

Tags: yarnpkg, yarn-v2

I faced some issues with yarn. Thus uninstalled and reinstalled it via homebrew (mac). Now on running any yarn command getting the below error (even on `yarn -v`)

```
Invariant Violation: Expected a key
    at invariant (/usr/local/Cellar/yarn/1.22.15/libexec/lib/cli.js:2314:15)
    at Parser.parse (/usr/local/Cellar/yarn/1.22.15/libexec/lib/cli.js:64434:55)
    at parse (/usr/local/Cellar/yarn/1.22.15/libexec/lib/cli.js:64581:21)
    at module.exports.exports.default (/usr/local/Cellar/yarn/1.22.15/libexec/lib/cli.js:64143:96)
    at loadRcFile (/usr/local/Cellar/yarn/1.22.15/libexec/lib/cli.js:56986:58)
    at /usr/local/Cellar/yarn/1.22.15/libexec/lib/cli.js:56960:14
    at /usr/local/Cellar/yarn/1.22.15/libexec/lib/cli.js:101468:14
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at parseRcPaths (/usr/local/Cellar/yarn/1.22.15/libexec/lib/cli.js:101466:78)
    at Object.findRc (/usr/local/Cellar/yarn/1.22.15/libexec/lib/cli.js:101480:10)
```

Since none of the yarn commands are working not able to clear the yarn cache as well. How to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ran into the same issue today, turns out it was caused by an empty string in the `yarn.lock` file:

```
"@dockite/field@>= 1.1.14", "", "@dockite/field@^1.1.0","@dockite/field@^1.1.33":
```